# Stop link from wrapping in emails

Tags: html, css, email

I have a footer for an email which contains three links in a line. On mobiles I would like these links to wrap in their entirety, but currently the links will break at things like `.co.uk` etc.

```
<td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" align="left" style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px; color: #999999; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; text-align: center; white-space:nowrap; border-collapse: collapse !important;" >
      <p>Some long address, PO Box 123, Someplace, Somewhere, SM1 3RE</p>
      <p style="white-space: nowrap;">
            <a href="tel:01234567891" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #b22024; white-space: nowrap;"><span style="white-space: nowrap;">0000 0000 000</span></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="mailto:someone@somewherelongplacename.co.uk" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #b22024; white-space: nowrap;"><span style="white-space: nowrap;">someone@somewherelongplacename.co.uk</span></a>&nbsp;
            <a href="https://somewherelongplacename.co.uk" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #b22024; white-space: nowrap;"><span style="white-space: nowrap;">somewherelongplacename.co.uk</span></a>
      </p>
</td>
```

This results in me seeing this:

```
0000 0000 000    someone@somewherelongplacename
.co.uk    somewherelongplacename.co.uk
```

But what i want would be this:

```
0000 0000 000
someone@somewherelongplacename.co.uk
somewherelongplacename.co.uk
```

Comment: Add `<br />` after the links? Or is it just for mobiles?

Comment: change their CSS style on mobile. display:block

Comment: Use css to change the `display` type to `block`. For example: `td p a { display: block; }`

Comment: @Morpheus unfortunately this is only for mobiles.

Comment: @abbas-nabilou gmail app doesnt recognise media queries so I can't see a way I can do this just for mobiles

Comment: so try adding your texts inside `<wbr> text <wbr>`

Comment: @AbbasNabilou unfortunately this hasnt worked either

Comment: you can try <nobr>someone@somewherelongplacename.co.uk</nobr>

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to force everything on one line as a group, try this:

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap; word-break: keep-all !important; hyphens: none;">
  SomeLongDarnTextYouWantToKeepFromBreaking
</span>

<span style="white-space: nowrap; word-break: keep-all !important; hyphens: none;">
  SomeAdditionalLongDarnTextYouWantToKeepFromBreaking
</span>
```

You might need to explore some combination to make things work. This is what I do to make a long `<H1>` break where I want it by wrapping the part I want to shift to a new line with a span tag.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you don't responsive layout or if you are using any framework like bootstrap you can use div classes for it.
Now here is a quick solution to solve the problem you are facing.
Step 1: Add this line in the head tag if it's not already there

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Step 2: Add a class named responsive to span tag

```
<td bgcolor="#f4f4f4" align="left" style="padding: 30px 30px 30px 30px; color: #999999; font-family: 'Lato', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-weight: 400; line-height: 18px; text-align: center; white-space:nowrap; border-collapse: collapse !important;" >
  <p>Some long address, PO Box 123, Someplace, Somewhere, SM1 3RE</p>
  <p style="white-space: nowrap;">
        <a href="tel:01234567891" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #b22024; white-space: nowrap;"><span style="white-space: nowrap;" class="responsive">0000 0000 000</span></a>&nbsp;
        <a href="mailto:someone@somewherelongplacename.co.uk" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #b22024; white-space: nowrap;"><span style="white-space: nowrap;" class="responsive">someone@somewherelongplacename.co.uk</span></a>&nbsp;
        <a href="https://somewherelongplacename.co.uk" style="text-decoration: underline; color: #b22024; white-space: nowrap;"><span style="white-space: nowrap;" class="responsive">somewherelongplacename.co.uk</span></a>
  </p>
```

Step 3:

```
<style type="text/css">
@media screen and (max-width: 620px) {
.responsive{
    display: block;
}
}
</style>
```

So basically you are checking if screen size is less than 620px it adds display: block to the span tag.